# Apple store apps won't download but have a iCloud symbol

Tags: iphone

I have downloaded the app before and then deleted by accedent but now it won't download at all and has a little cloud symbol instead of an install symbol

Comment: What happens if you tap on the cloud symbol?

Answer (score 3):

I know my answer might be late for you, but maybe it can help somebody else. I had the SAME frustrating problem with the GOOGLE CHROME APP and I solved it this way:

1. Go to Settings --> Storage & iCloud Usage
2. Go to the section that says ICLOUD
3. Click on Manage Storage
4. Click on Joana's (Your name) iPhone
5. At the Backup Options turn off Chrome
6. Go to the App Store and try to download the app again. Hopefully, it will start downloading! For me this solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

These might look obvious but it's always best to check:

1. Make sure you're connected to the internet and that you have a good, strong signal.
2. Do you have enough space available on your device?  You didn't mention the device or space used but if you don't have enough space available for the app, it won't download.
3. Do other apps download?  Try downloading a free app.  This makes sure your network settings are not messed up.
4. Reboot your device and try again.
5. Reset your Network settings to the defaults.  Go to `Settings --> General --> Reset --> Reset Network Settings`.  You'll lose the login user id & password from every network you've been on, so be prepared with that info in order to log in to your wifi networks.
6. If all those fail, it's time to contact Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Choose any new app and try to install that. And as that install is going on, hit the cloud download on the app that was frozen/stuck. With any luck the frozen app will start downloading too. This is how it got sorted on my side today. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I switched off the iCloud Drive and reinstalled from the Applestore the app which was still showing the cloud icon. It worked because it showed the latest update instead of the old one which had not changed when the app opened.

Answer (score -1):

If you have time warner cable/spectrum or a new router or internet, you must login and make sure your device is trusted. I did this and it fixed everything.

Answer (score -3):

Try to clear up the memory, at least 1 GB. Then, try to download.

Answer (score -4):

i had the same prob for watsapp app try checking ur apple id it must be on verfication try siging out nd signing inn ur apple id and then download. also check your i cloud back ups

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, the reason you're getting down votes is that your answer is not well written and this makes it hard to follow. I strongly suggest you revisit your answer so that the community can fully benefit from it.